# Validating Input Data in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am working on a spring boot project. I am building a PUT/POST API which takes boolean data type in the request body. The issue is whenever I pass an integer value like 12,13,-15... etc it converts it to true (which is the default behavior of boolean), but my doubt is, is their a way to validate here such that it takes only 0,1, true and false. I tried adding the regex to  validation.properties and @ESAPI annotations to my model, but I've read that data canonicalization happens before validation occurs. so I am stuck with this issue, How do I resolve this?

This is a PUT Request.
Here is the  Request body

```
{
  "access": true,

  "prefLanguage": "English",

  "prefTimeZone": "USA"
}
```

My Model is defined as

```
public class Consent implements Serializable {

    @ESAPIPattern(validateWithPattern = "acess", required = true)
    private String acess;
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    @ESAPIPattern(allowNull = true,validateWithPattern = "prefTimeZone")
    private String prefTimeZone;
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    @ESAPIPattern(allowNull = true,validateWithPattern = "prefLanguage")
    private String prefLanguage;

... getters and setters 
}
```

Here I want "access" to accept only true|false or 0|1, I don't want it to accept any other integer value.

Comment: Could you add your code snippet? some [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), maybe also provide more information about the context and ask specifically where you need help?

Comment: {
  "acess": true,
  "prefLanguage": "USA",
  "prefTimeZone": "USA"
} here access is a boolean value and i need to bound it to either true or false or 0 or 1 , but i think if its bound to true|false only that will work for me

Comment: Please add code snippet in your **original question**, not in the comments. Also, that JSON only is not sufficient, provide code which you're having problem with. Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a context validator which is provided by spring. You can create an annotation @BoolenValidator and put it in the request param or path variable.

```
public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
boolean isValid = true;

if (isNull(value) || !(value==0|| value==1)) {
  isValid =  addViolation(value, "must be 0 or 1");
}
return isValid;
}
```